# Not getting same result from numpy.cov(m, rowvar= False) as Octave

Tags: python, octave

I am trying to achieve a result where cov() in Octave gives 2x2 matrix whereas in Numpy it gives an integer. I have tried setting rowvar= False as I saw in other threads but it yields the same result. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the code I'm trying to execute:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import svd, sqrtm, inv
from scipy.io import wavfile
import utilities as utl
#import scipy.linalg
import statistics as st
#import pandas

# Specify the name
name = ["x", "y"]

# Read the mixed signals
x1, Fs1 = wavfile.read('./sounds/source' + name[0] + '.wav')
x2, Fs2 = wavfile.read('./sounds/source' + name[1] + '.wav')

xx = [x1, x2]
xxt = np.transpose(xx)

covt = np.cov(xx,rowvar=False)
#inv= inv(cov)
print (covt)
```

The result I get from this is 7605000.0 whereas when it is run on Octave it gives the output as `0.04365166799  -0.00000071823 -0.00000071823   0.04380681998`

What should I do?
I know that different libraries use different iterations of cov(), but Pandas' and Octave's iteration are similar and give  similar output but I dont know how to implement Pandas.

Any help is appreciated, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

According to the wavread documentation, you have the "sampling rate" and "data" the other way round.

It should have been

```
Fs1, x1 = wavfile.read( 'blabla.wav' )
```

instead.